# Angular5 Karma test: Rxjs operator is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, karma-runner

I have a component (MyComponent) that uses mergeMap - it builds, runs and does everything I want. No problems here. I removed the real implementation for this example.

During the Karma test I get an error thrown `'service.$find(...).mergeMap is not a function'`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

export component MyComponent {
  constructor(private service: Service) {
    let observable = service.$find().mergeMap(() => { return Observable.of() });
  }
}
```

I mock this service for the test: service.mock.ts

```
export class MockService {
  $find() { return Observable.of() }
}
```

I test this component in mycomponent.spec.ts

```
describe("MyComponent", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: Service, useClass: Mockservice}],
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    })
  }
  // setup and it("should create") ...

}
```

I tried `import {mergeMap} from "rxjs/Operators/mergeMap";` at several places as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Observable patching to add operators you need to add them from `rxjs/add/operator/xyz`:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

For Observable (or static methods on the Observable class that create new Observables):

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Or if this is only for your tests you could import from `rxjs` like (this loads all patches from `rxjs/add` as well):

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

Note, that this will include everything so it's not recommended in production.